# Ram memory consumption continuously increasing on simple page refresh Node.js using Sails.js Framework

Tags: javascript, node.js, sails.js

I have a Sails JS app which initially starts at memory 1.2 % of my 8GB RAM and when i continuously refresh the page it jumps of to 3 to 4.1 % and which is never released . I have a heap snapshot and have refactored all the code but still the issue is same (Removed any timers ,global variables from clientside and server side script).

Is this issue with sails app as there are many tickets on git but without any conclusion and what are the necessary steps that can be taken to resolve this .

I have snapshot of heap using heapdump which are taken manually and i can share it with you .
Heap Snapshots

[Before Load](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7fbKzafcDfCb1ZHNFU5aHVBUlk&usp=sharing)

[After Load 414 MB](https://drive.google.com/folderview?id=0B7fbKzafcDfCSk5xRDE0UUFTdjQ&usp=sharing)

Comment: The answer is 42... No seriously, how is anyone supposed to answer this ? http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask I suggest you learn to debug. http://sailsjs.org/documentation/reference/command-line-interface/sails-debug

Comment: Its not a syntax error that i am talking about that can be found using debug . If it was so simple i wouldn't have shared heap snapshots if you know to debug look at the snapshots and answer the questions.

Comment: What version of Node are you using?  Certain release of Node 0.12.x had serious memory issues.  There is a [rather lengthy discussion](https://github.com/balderdashy/sails/issues/3099) about this in the Sails Github forum.  The solution is to upgrade to Node 4+

Answer (score 0):

Your question is too broad to be answered directly.  Usually the best way to track down resource leaks is to profile your application.  Here's a page introducing profiling with Node: https://nodejs.org/en/docs/guides/simple-profiling/